# Xamarin application crashes on startup on release mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, release

as I said in the title, my application simply works fine in debug mode, but when I extract a release mode apk it just crashes on startup.

I have tried every possible fix I could found on google and none worked, that's what I tried so far:-

1. Setting linking to **None** / **SDK Assemblies Only**.
2. Setting code shrinker to **None** / **ProGaurd**.
3. Enabling support architectures **armeabi-v7a** and **arm64-v8a**.
4. Adding **Internet** permission.
5. Cleaning the whole solution and rebuilding everything.
6. Setting projects assemblies (PCL & Android & IOS) to lowercase names fails the archiving.
7. Enabling the **Use Shared Runtime** fails the archiving.
8. Enabling the **Bundle assemblies into native code**.
9. Uninstalling the **Mono Shared Runtime** from the device.

I also cleaned the solution and did a rebuild after each of these tries...

Nothing worked...
What am I missing here ?!
Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: Does the crash happens before or after the splash screen (if you have one)

Comment: Crashes during the splash screen, I have XML splash screen that appears while the application loads. Specifically during some actions while in the App() onCreate.

Comment: Please, provide some code to see what you're doing.

Comment: Tried on device or just in the emulator? Do you have any compiler #if statements?

Comment: Have you tried to build it on an emulator in the release configuration, does it still crash? If so, try to enable debug symbols and debugging in the release configurations as well, and you should be able to catch the exception.

Comment: Well, I disabled all my startup codes that run in the App() constructor and still crashes...

Comment: No, I tried on a physical device, and No, I don't have any compiler #if statements...

Comment: No, I didn't try running in release on an emulator, will try now and see if it still crashes...

Comment: @Saamer , You actually helped me, using emulator failed which drived me towards using debugging again on emulator only in release mode, I discovered the issue. I can add that as an answer so I can accept it ^_^

Comment: @MohamedAshraf thats awesome! I added that as an answer, does that look good? Btw, what was the issue caused from?

Comment: The answer is okay <3
The issue was that when the App constructor sets `MainPage = new Main();`, that Main() 's constructor itself tries to access an object that is null **ONLY WHEN THE APPLICATION IS LAUNCHED FOR THE FIRST TIME !** I know it seems like a noob issue and it's very awkward, but I guess I learned to remove everything and debug the app from scratch one more time before releasing xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MohamedAshraf mentioned, when he tried to build it on an emulator in the release configuration, the app still crashed.

So, he was able to enable debug symbols and debugging in the release configurations as well, and was able to catch the exception and fix the issue.

Don't forget to turn debugging off in the release config again afterwards.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I want to share what worked for me: In the Code Shrinker option, I cleared the dropdown option. So, no R8 and no Proguard, select the blank option and voala....

Comment: @washington-morais it seems like you need a proguard file, which is why you are facing the crash

Comment: proguard is more like a pro-Killer. tried many configurations and none worked. the only thing that worked was like I said, a blank option.